# Subtotolas between elements repititions showing all elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, report, xslt-2.0

I want to know how to show a subtotal between XML repeated elements like this:

```
<ITEMS>
   <ITEM>
      <CODE>001</CODE>
      <QUANTITY>10</QUANTITY>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      <CODE>001</CODE>
      <QUANTITY>10</QUANTITY>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      <CODE>002</CODE>
      <QUANTITY>2</QUANTITY>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      <CODE>002</CODE>
      <QUANTITY>3</QUANTITY>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      <CODE>003</CODE>
      <QUANTITY>5</QUANTITY>
   </ITEM>
   <ITEM>
      <CODE>003</CODE>
      <QUANTITY>-3</QUANTITY>
   </ITEM>
</ITEMS>
```

Into a list like this:

```
Item  001, quantity 10
Item  001, quantity 10
           subtotal 20
    
Item 002, quantity  2
Item 002, quantity  3
          subtotal  5

Item 003, quantity  5
Item 003, quantity -3
          subtotal  2
```

Using XSLT for this, in the best and simplest way.

Comment: To realize that, you have to use [Muenchian Grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html). Also note that your question does not comprise a [mcve]. So update your question with your XSLT-1.0 attempt at Muenchian Grouping.

Comment: This is a *grouping* question. Do a search - it's probably the most often asked XSLT question here. Note that answers are different for XSLT 1.0 or 2.0+.

Answer (score 1):

use below code:

```
<xsl:template match="ITEMS">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="ITEM" group-by="CODE">
        <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat('Item ', CODE, ', quantity ', QUANTITY, '&#xa;')"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:value-of select="concat('          subtotal ', sum(current-group()/QUANTITY), '&#xa;&#xa;')"/>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

See Transformation at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6pS2B77/1

**Output**

```
Item 001, quantity 10
Item 001, quantity 10
          subtotal 20

Item 002, quantity 2
Item 002, quantity 3
          subtotal 5

Item 003, quantity 5
Item 003, quantity -3
          subtotal 2
```

Comment: Thanks. It helped me a lot!